# Converging Diverging Nozzles

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am studying about the modelling of an ejector system. Here it is a single phase ejector with steam as the motive fluid and hydrocarbon vapor as the suction fluid. 
[image: a typical ejector system]The motive fluid is expanded through a converging-diverging nozzle. The vacuum is created to draw in the suction fluid by allowing the steam to expand to a pressure less than the suction fluid pressure.

The steam enters at 16 bar to the nozzle, expands to a final pressure of .02133 bar. I am considering that the area ratios are large enough to allow such an expansion to take place. But then if we apply the nozzle equations,
[For exit temperature and pressure 3rd and 4th equations](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/rktthsum.html)

I got the mach number to be about **4.114** and the temperature ratio to be about **0.467** . This means that the nozzle exit temperature is **221.535 K** (**-51.46 celsius)!**
Does this mean that the steam is converting to water and freezing.

Temperature relation:-

[image: Temperature relation]

Pressure relation:-

[image: Pressure relation]

Many Thanks

Edit: I came across a [reputed book on heat transfer in general](http://www.thermodynamicsheatengines.com/HeatEnginesVol_2_Chapter_8_RS.pdf) and the first example in this book is similar to mine. The problem is that they assumed the steam to have its temperature determined from the nozzle exit pressure and the dryness fraction. Please help me with the concept if possible :). The temperature of the steam at nozzle inlet is 201.3 degree celsius (saturated) and the suction inlet is 55 degree celsius.

Is it actually because of the nature of the expansion process? It proceeds very rapidly and there might be very less time for steam to change phase. So the steam might remain at its saturation temperature and at the nozzle exit it comes into contact with the hotter suction side fluid and condenses instantly. But even then why does it not freeze? Is it due to mixing with the hotter suction fluid?

Comment: Can anyone share their thoughts please? :(